# How to remove files, that were created more than 5 minutes ago on Linux using command find & -delete?

Tags: bash

I found, that command find has option "-detete", that allows to remove found files, but the problem is it removes even folder, where removed files are located. I just need to remove files and folder should be present. 
Here is the command, that I use:

```
find /home/myuser/test/ -mmin +5 -delete
```

If all files in directory test were created 10 minutes ago folder test will be removed, but I need to remove only files within test directory. How can I fix this ?

Comment: Add `-type f` to find only normal files, not directories ( nor fifos, device files, etc )

Comment: hey, thanks for answer! you mean like this: find /home/myuser/test/ -type f -mmin +5 -delete ?

Comment: Yes, that'll work. (BTW, in general, Stack Overflow's focus is on questions exclusively/specifically relevant to *software development*; general-purpose of UNIX tools is typically a better fit for our sister site [unix.se]).

Comment: okay, I got this, thanks!